# Divisibility in a set

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $A$ be a set consisting of positive integers. If there exists an integer $k > 1$ such that any consecutive $k$ positive integers has a nonempty intersection with $A$. Show that $A$ contains two elements $a, b$ such that $a$ divides $b$.

I have no idea how to do it. Could anybody help me?

Comment: Could you please provide some context for this question. More specifically, this site is (for details see 'faq', link at the top) for questions related to current research in mathematics. Thus, if this question arose in such a context this is fine for this site, if not then not. Thus it is important to know the context. Thanks in advance.     

Comment: I don't know if it is that important. Maybe it is very simple, maybe not. This comes from a problem book of elementary number theory. I tried some of them. Most of them are of the level of Olympic competition. You may decide if it is interesting. I want to solve it just for the reason of curiosity. 

Comment: It seems it should have an easier answer, but one way to see it is that the density of $nA$ is $1/n$ times the density of $A$. Because the density of $A$ is at least $1/k>0$ and $\sum 1/n$ gets arbitrarily large we have that $A$ intersects $nA$ for some $n$ and then we are done (I can write this better if requested)

Comment: Joel: I don't see your argument. The fact that $\sum 1/n$ gets arbitrarily large only implies (to me) that the sets $nA$ are not all disjoint.

Comment: @ksj03: thank you for the reply. In view of this context, it seems that other sites mentioned in the FAQ might be a better fit, specifically the Art of Problem Solving comes to mind (though I do not really know that site well) or perhaps also http://math.stackexchange.com 

Comment: Idea: prove that we may assume there exists at least k mutually coprime integers and invoke CRT. 

Comment: GH: Ah, you're right, that's not enough... Also, if it took a paper of Erdos to settle this, it may not be that easy to solve just using the fact that it has positive density.

Answer (score 5):

The set $A$ has positive lower density, hence the result follows from the main theorem in [this paper](http://renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1935-04.pdf) of Paul Erdős (the proof takes one page).